# JPA: How to delete the child of self type?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Consider the class

```
@Entity
public class CustomType {

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Column
  private CustomType child;

}
```

I have a situation where I can delete `child` entity and I would like it to cascade to it `parent`

When I try to do that, I see

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'CustomType' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK197854DCA5BD6640' for key (bece5b16-fafd-49fd-9ff3-cc19b050e174).  The statement has been rolled back.
```

What is that I am missing?

Comment: It would be helpful to look at the generated SQL to see how the constraint being violated is defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE on table 'CustomType' caused a violation of foreign key constraint
```

It means that row's id of your row you are trying to delete has reference in another table and for this reason cannot be deleted.

This row can be deleted only when references to row no longer exist in other table(s).